# How to subscribe to a JMS topic from javascript - need a full example

Tags: javascript, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I'm  using an active mq to generated jMs topic messages and I would like to be able to subscribe to a particular topic from javasript.
I need a full example on how to do this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with websockets like this
https://github.com/apache/activemq/tree/master/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/websocket

https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/blob/master/example/chat/index.html

http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html

There are many libs and examples https://github.com/krukow/stomple/blob/master/example/transactional-chat.html